# AngularJS - replacing a value in the view or controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to bind a value coming from the model in a `span` element, but I need to replace some characters.

I figured I have two options:

1. Call the Javascript replace method when binding:

   {{ myValue.replace("a", "A"); }}
2. Have a `myReplace` function in the controller and call it when binding from the view:

   // Controller:
   vm.myReplace = function(string) { return string.replace("a", "A"); }
   // View:
   {{ vm.myReplace(value) }}

I am wondering if there are any other options, and what is the recommended way (or most common way) in AngularJS. Thank You.

Comment: you can do same with using a `filter` in angularjs

Comment: Yes, this is actually a perfect usecase for filters :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go for a filter for the use case you're describing. That way it also changes automatically as your text changes.

It goes like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div>{{name | replaceA}}</div>
```

**Filter:**

```
filterExample.filter('replaceA', function () {
    return function (text) {
        if (!text) {
            return text;
        }

        return text.replace(/\a/g, 'A'); // Replaces all occurences
    };
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5WnTA/120/)